# Looking to create a cumulative column in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset

Example Dataset:

record_id admin_dt_1

1    June 7th 2022

2    August 25th 2022

3    August 23rd 2022

4    July 8th 2022

5    August 5th 2022

I would like my output to show in the first column September 1st...2nd...so on to 30th which I have done but I would like the second column to  show the number of people eligible for each day in September. Eligible means anyone after 28 days from their admin_dt_1. I also want the column to be cumulative it should look something like this: Since there are 5 data points it should add up to 5 in the frequency column.

Date       Frequency eligible

September 1st    3

September 30th  5

```
data dose2eligible;
set request;
/*create September 1st to September 30th date*/
 do  date= '01sep2022'd to '30sep2022'd; 
 output;
 end;
  format
    date date9.;
run;
proc freq data=dose2eligible; table date;  run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Count the number of days between `admin_dt_1` and `date`, then create a 1/0 flag using the shortcut `var = (boolean comparision)`:

`eligible = (admin_dt_1 - date > 28);`

```
data dose2eligible;
    set request;

    /*create September 1st to September 30th date*/
    do  date= '01sep2022'd to '30sep2022'd; 
        eligible = (admin_dt_1 - date > 28);
        output;
    end;
 
    format date date9.;
run;
```

You can then count the number of eligible people on each date:

```
proc sql;
    select date
         , sum(eligible) as total_eligible
    from dose2eligible
    group by date;
quit;
```

Comment: Note there is no need to use INTCK() for intervals that are the same as the unit that is used to denominate the values. So DAY for date values or SECOND for time or datetime values.  Simple arithmetic operators will work.